# How to optimize nested table load which is built with ng-repeat and ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

Currently Chrome loads the table of size 40x15 in about 6 seconds. It's much slower than goog.editor.Table. I need to cut the load time at least twice.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid_item_renderer.html">
<span ng-switch on="cell.type">
    <textarea ng-switch-when="simple" class="cell-text-area simple-cell" ng-model="cell.data">{{cell.data}}</textarea>
    <span ng-switch-when="grid">
        <table class="declarative-grid-table" border="1" bordercolor="#CCC" cellspacing="0" tabindex="0">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in cell.data.grid" >
                <td ng-repeat="cell in row" class="declarative-grid-cell">
                    <span ng-include="'grid_item_renderer.html'"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>unexpected cell type</span>
</span>
</script>
<table class="declarative-grid-table" border="1" bordercolor="#CCC" cellspacing="0"  tabindex="0">
<tr ng-repeat="row in declarativeGrid" class="declarative-grid-row">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in row" class="declarative-grid-cell">
        <span ng-include="'grid_item_renderer.html'"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Angular you're able to optimize however much you might need to by creating custom directives.  If you're experiencing performance issues with nested ng-repeats, it might be time to roll your own directive that builds the DOM elements of your table programmatically. It would be a lot faster and a lot less overhead, because there would be fewer $watches and scopes created by your custom directive.

Comment: Thanks. That's correct, but I feel like directives is kind of anti-pattern. When you turn from html to directive you turn from declarative and short code to imperative and lengthy. Though I'm not sure. Anyway, we decided to use Closure for grid and Angular for everything else.

Comment: Yeah, optimization in general can feel like an anti-pattern sometimes. I know I did some performance tweaks to a graphics processing engine I wrote a while back and the code went from easy to follow to complete spaghetti... but it was several times faster. Every time I tried to go in and clean it up, I couldn't get around a few of the optimizations I made that made it "dirty". Haha... oh well. That's the job we're paid for I suppose.